# createCriteria is not valid without active transaction

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm using `Spring 4.1.3.RELEASE` and `Hibernate 4.3.7`.

The following issue came up while I was trying to use both `JTA` transaction and `Hibernate` criteria-query. Code:

```
@Resource
private UserTransaction userTransaction;

@Resource
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public User getUserById(Integer id){
    try {
        userTransaction.begin();
    } catch (Exception e) { }
    Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("id", id));
    try {
        userTransaction.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) { }
    return (User) criteria.uniqueResult();
}
```

I got the Exception that createCriteria is not valid without active transaction. By going through the method's code with a debugger I ensured that I had a valid `JTA` -  transaction. What was wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have setup hibernate to integrate with JTA correctly.

Comment: @M.Deinum Do you mean the `<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>`? Currently it's setted to thread. Is that worng?

Comment: Once you are spring based why don't you want to manage your transactions using spring? take a look at the link:
http://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/

Comment: That is wrong yes that is for local transaction not JTA. But as mentioned by @Hazhir if you use Spring use that to manage and configure your transactions, saves you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you are spring based why don't you want to manage your transactions using spring? take a look at the link:
[Configuring Spring and JTA without full Java EE](http://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting an exception on the userTransaction.begin(). Your catch does nothing so the createCriteria() fails because you don't have a transaction.